# Application of Contraction Principle?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, alternative-proof

> Show that there is a unique solution to the equation \begin{equation} \frac{df}{dx}=(f(x)+x)x \tag{*}\end{equation}
>   for $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f(0)=0$.

Clearly, $(*)$ is a first order linear ordinary differential equation and so, by the *Picard-Lindelöf theorem*, there should exist a unique solution. **Nevertheless,** I am not able to use this result as it stands since it is not part of the course I am currently reading. Instead, I was thinking of using the *Contraction Principle*. However, I am not entirely sure as to how I should accomplish this, any suggestions?

Comment: Well, by linearity you can say that if you have two solutions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ and define $g(x)$ as their difference, then $g(x)$ satisfies $g'(x) = xg(x)$.  Perhaps that is easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As remarked in the comment, there is another (way easier) way to solve the uniqueness. If you really want to use contraction mapping theorem:

Let $\mathscr C = \{ f \in C[0,1]: f(0) = 0\}$. $\mathscr C$ is a Banach space with norm

$$||f|| = \sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)|.$$

Define $\Phi : C\to C$ by

$$\Phi(f) (x) = \int_0^x (f(s) + s)s ds . $$

Then for any $f, g\in \mathscr C$
$$|| \Phi (f)- \Phi(g)|| \leq \int_0^x  s|f(s) - g(s)|ds \leq ||f - g||\int_0^x s ds \leq \frac 12 ||f-g||$$

Thus $\Phi$ is a contraction and so there is a unique $f\in \mathscr C$ so that

$$f(x) = \Phi(f) (x)= \int_0^x (f(s) + s)sds \Rightarrow \frac{df}{dx} (x)= (f(x) + x)x.$$

Comment: Brilliant! That is more than I could have hoped for...